# how to read value from Json flutter

Tags: flutter

hello i have an object Json which have some values as payload , key ,  card .. so i aim to get the data i need directly with key "payload" .

```
      var dataFinal= tag.data.toString();
```

and this what i get if i print my data

```
[log] handle {nfca: {identifier: [12, 4, 18, 17], atqa: [4, 0], maxTransceiveLength: 253, sak: 8, timeout: 618}, mifareclassic: {identifier: [99, 4, 150, 17], blockCount: 64, maxTransceiveLength: 253, sectorCount: 16, size: 1024, timeout: 618, type: 0}, ndef: {identifier: [99, 4, 150, 17], isWritable: true, maxSize: 716, canMakeReadOnly: false, cachedMessage: {records: [{typeNameFormat: 1, type: [84], identifier: [], payload: [1,45,989]}]}, type: com.nxp.ndef.mifareclassic}}
```

how can i get the payload value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the function `jsonDecode()` which expects a string as a param and returns `dynamic` or `Map` in your case

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Map<String,dynamic> data = jsonDecode(tag.data.toString());
print(data["nfca"]);
```